# Troubleshooting Google App Script JSON conversion, "Expected end of stream at char X"

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am getting data from a website via REST API that returns data in JSON text format. I'm trying to get the app script to pull information for use in the Google Data Studio.

The snippet of code I'm using to get the text and try converting it in the Google script editor is:

```
function getData(request) {

var optionsPost = {
  "method" : "get",
  "headers":{
    "Authorization": "Basic (base64encodedinfo)",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
  },
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://myapiserver.com/results/recordid?from=2018-09-12T00:00:00Z&to=2018-09-13T23:00:00Z&rs=HOUR&tz=0&format=JSON',optionsPost);
var responseText = response.getContentText();
var responseJSON = JSON.parse(responseText);
Logger.log(responseJSON);
}
```

Hitting the run button keeps returning "SyntaxError: Expected end of stream at char 196 (line 170, file "Code")" with the line number pointing to the JSON.parse(responseJSON) line.

If I send responseText to Logger.log, the text is cut off, but from what I can find Google's view->log truncates information.

Sending response.getContentText().length to Logger.log results in "572056.0" to view->log.

Is this saying that there's a formatting problem in the response text that the JSON library can't parse, or is it somehow getting cut off? Is there a function in Google App Script that can sanitize the text before parsing it?

Update:
Does JSON.parse() require newlines or line breaks of some kind between JSON record entries in order to correctly parse it?

Comment: Wrap your code in a try {} catch {} block.  I'm getting an error in your url.

Comment: @TheWizEd the url is just an example.

Comment: You can try logging your data response to Stackdriver. Depending how large it is, it may not be displayed. I think 500kb is likely to be too large. Alternately, print the content to a spreadsheet.

Comment: @WelcometoStackOverflow Yes, when logging the getContentText().length in the scripting UI that's what it sends to the log. At this point after more rubber ducking and some poking with output, I suspect it's a formatting issue with the output from the API call (if that is the issue, I'll revisit this question and put in an answer so people can tell that kind of odd error from the JS call can be triggered by a format issue in the JSON it's trying to read)

Comment: Did you resolve the problem in your code? I notice an “Update” question but Its not clear whether that is solved or not.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks for prompting for the promised update! It seems that while the code I had, itself, was fine, when running with introduced data the JSON library was failing to properly translate a small formatting issue with the data and didn't spit out a meaningful error. Nothing was coming up in the dialog and nothing appeared in the logs until I narrowed down what kind of message to check for. In short...JSON can be a PITA to translate and error check sometimes...

Comment: @BartSilverstrim Heh, reminds me of the favour saying of a friend at Uni - "never assume". But it sounds like you're good to go. AAMO, have you tried [JSON Line](https://jsonlint.com/) (or similar)?

Comment: @Tedinoz Re: JSON Line - Yup, that was one of the sites (among a few) that I ended up visiting as I fell down the "I think the JSON interpreter thinks this is broken" rabbit hole...helped me narrow down where exactly the string was failing!